# How to add shadow to the FAB provided with the material design library?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

this is the FAB I am using `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`
tried backgroundTint not working And `android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/fabShadowColor"` working on API level 28 and above.

And here is my FAB code

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navHomeBtn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/home_ic"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/fabShadowColor"
        app:fabCustomSize="50dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomNav"
        app:maxImageSize="50dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fabShadowColor"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_container"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"
        tools:targetApi="p" />
```

Comment: Do you mean the elevation attr? 
Try to set a elevation value (in dp) on your xml

Comment: I have edited my question and added my FAB code. It is showing gray shadow by default but I want to change it to my custom color